# How to implement multiple table inheritance in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I did some searching but couldn’t find a good solution for my problem. Anyway, I am really new to Laravel and this is my first project, I appreciate your help.

In my project, these is **staffs** table in database which holds the records for four types of staff (`Staff`, `Manager`, `SalePersonnel` and `Secretary`) and each of these three types have special attributes . However, storing all type of stuff in one table results a lot of **NULLS**.

I want to separate the staffs table into four tables, one parent table that has common attributes of all staff and three more table for each type of staff.

How can I do this in Laravel context? How to create a parent  record and child record. Please provide a detailed answer.

Sorry for being that dumb, as I said I am new to Laravel.

Comment: Please read about [Polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you think that will work instead of multiple inheritance?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: Thank you am really grateful from your help.

Comment: Great! So I believe you got your answer?

Comment: Yes! I got my answer